# Trying to enter Diagnostic connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

SQL Server 2014, SP3  Need to establish diagnostic connection.  When I open Mgmt Studio, click on database engine query, and type in admin:MSSQLSERVER (we use the default instance on this box)  I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MSSQLSERVER'

Can someone tell me the correct syntax?

I have tried:

```
admin:servername\MSSQLSERVER
admin:servername
```

both give same syntax error near whatever is first typed after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved:

When I click on the Database Engine Query button, in the login screen that pops up, put ADMIN: in front of the server name, and connect.  This worked for me.